# Limitar quantidade de linhas de uma textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

É possível limitar a quantidade de linhas em uma `textbox` multiline usando C# NET 3.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não existe uma propriedade que limite o número de linhas do `TextBox`, apenas o número de caracteres.

Nada impede, no entanto, que você implemente o evento `KeyDown`, fazendo uma contagem de linhas e evite que seja criada uma nova quando atingir o limite.

Supondo que você esteja utilizando winforms:

```
int maxLines = 3;        
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Split('\n').Length >= maxLines)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Lembrando que seria necessário setar a propriedade `WordWrap` para `false` afim de evitar que o `TextBox` exiba uma nova linha quando o texto chegar ao final.

Comment: Isso se a pessoa der `enter`, caso ela digitar um texto imenso não vai pegar né?

Comment: Acabei de acrescentar uma observação sobre isso. Caso não seja desativado o WordWrap eu não entenderia o sentido de se limitar o número de linhas e não o de caracters.

Comment: Vi agora e concordo com você, acho até melhor apenas limitar a quantidade de caracteres do que de linhas.